# Assembly: Format of input characters

Tags: assembly, x86, character

I'm a bit of confused in inputted characters. When I input a character, the inputted character is then stored in al. So, what's the format of that inputted character? Is it in hex or decimal?

I need to know because I'll use it in a nested loop. It's my first time to use an inputted character as a limiter in a loop.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexadecimal, decimal, binary, etc are just ways of *representing* data. If you input the ASCII character 'A' into register `AL` it has the same value regardless of representation, i.e. register `AL` contains `65` (decimal) which is the same as `0x41` (hex) or `01000001b` (binary). In other words it's the same *bit pattern* in the register, it's just up to you how you choose to *represent* it.

Comment: When I input a number, it's in ASCII, not integer. Hmm. Is it okay if I add the simple code I'm working on here? (The reason I asked the question above)I don't know why it's not working properly when I put al but when I replaced al with a specific ASCII character, it's working properly.

Comment: @shriekyphantom: The point is, the character `A` has *only* one value, 65 (decimal). So even if the some programmers call it 65, others call it 0x41, and others 0b010000001. The point is, the value is the same. (Although, technically, all numbers on the computer are binary).

Comment: It's ok now. I just learned that you can't use al in an iteration. Thanks for replying by the way. :)

Comment: Actually, yes you can use AL in an iteration.  I am guessing you have something in AL, then go an put something in EAX which is destroying what is in AL.